# Make a .JAR file using classes, ERROR : invalid or corrupted file

Tags: java, jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Corrupt jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559072/corrupt-jar-file)

I made a game in Eclipse and packaged all the class files in `test.jar`. When I attempt to run it, it gives me the error:

> ```
> Error: invalid or corrupted jar file.
> ```

I opened the `.jar` file using Winrar, and everything is in there.

I have looked for a similar question on Stack OverFlow, but didn't find any. Can you explain to me how I can solve this error?

***FOR EVERYONE WITH THIS PROBLEM ,SOLUTION:***
Go to file, export, export as a Runnable Jar, Select your main class, finish.
If you want to run your program in cmd, create a new textfile, and type java -jar project.jar with project = name of your program.
Save this as Run.bat
then open the Run.bat, it will automatically open project.jar
Thats it, it worked for me!

Comment: How do you create the jar file?

Comment: Is the manifest file the first entry in the zip file list? I heard that Java is picky about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you place your classes to tar.jar? A valid jar file must follow some rules it requires. You'd best generate them by your Eclipse tools. click "export" -> "jar" and select the right entry of your game. Good Luck.