# Invalid jar file

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have created a App Client application that I want to deploy through web start. The app works in Eclipse and I have self-signed the jar file within the ear file. When I click the link to download it I get the message:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid jar file
```

What do I have to do to clear this?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jme3/app/SimpleApplication
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
```

[edit update]
The jar file now runs locally after I used the export option to include dependant libraries. I have self-signed the jar file but I still get an invalid jar file response through webstart. The jars size is now 150mb does that cause an issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Corrupt jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559072/corrupt-jar-file)

Answer (score 1):

This happens when  the JAR is by itself actually not an executabele JAR. A real **executable** JAR should have at least a class with a `main()` method and have it referenced in `MANIFEST.MF`. Important in Eclipse is that you export your JAR as **runnable JAR file**.

see [Corrupt jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559072/corrupt-jar-file) or [Make a .JAR file using classes, ERROR : invalid or corrupted file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911476/make-a-jar-file-using-classes-error-invalid-or-corrupted-file)

Comment: I have done that (well made it exe after) I think it is classes required, separate lib, are not brought into the jar that is causing it.

Comment: Is it possible to run the jar on the command line. Maybe it helps if you post the whole stack trace not only the message.

Comment: Added the stack trace how do I add the classes required to the output jar file? They are on the class path in Eclipse but not getting into the jar.

Comment: JARs don't contain dependend jars. You need to specify the dependent jars within your [jnlp file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlpFileSyntax.html). As a workaround you can expand the dependent jar(s) and include the classes in your jar. There is a [WebStart Plugin](http://webstart.sourceforge.net) available for eclipse which helps you to create the JNLP file.

Comment: I didn't need a separate plugin I was able to do it through the Eclipse menu. I now have all the classes inside the jar and it runs from the cmd with no errors. I am still getting invalid jar when attempting to get it through web start. It is big though 150mb.

Comment: Is the error still the same i.e. ClassNotFoundException? What happens if you run your application from the javaws commandline tool passing your jnlp file? Is it possible to download the jar. Is it identical to the original jar file?

Comment: The error is still the same from webstart (invalid jar file) and I have cleared the ClassNotFoundException when running from cmd (java -jar <filename>). I will try it with javaws later when I get home. I suspect this is me getting the jnlp wrong though.