# Why java complains about jar files with lots of entries?

Tags: java, scala, jar, zip, java-7

I stumbled upon following problem - when I create `.jar` file with more than 65k entries, java complains "Invalid or corrupt jarfile". Example:

```
$ # in fresh dir
$ for i in {1..70000}; do touch $i; done
$ jar cf app.jar {1..70000}
$ java -jar app.jar
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile app.jar
```

But if I use a bit less files, it works:

```
$ jar cf app.jar {1..60000}
$ java -jar app.jar
no main manifest attribute, in app.jar
```

I heard that there was 65k files limit in old `.zip` file format, but Java 7 should use ZIP64 by default already. Why is this happening? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: A JAR is Java's variation of ZIP.  While it might have fixed some issues, it could be behind for other improvements. I suggest you not put some many files in a JAR in the first place ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Yes, splitting stuff between several smaller .jar files is the obvious workaround, but it is very clunky. Anyway, it's not normal to have such low limit on file amount. Maybe there's already opened bug about this?

Comment: I would hope so, but you can always log another one if you can't find it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - found it! http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7191282

Comment: Seems the fix is only going to come to us in Java 8 :(

Comment: The old backward compatibility problem I suspect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

It's a bug in Java 1.7.0 (aka Java 7)

- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7191282.

Fixed in Java 1.7.0 p40 or later, apparently.

> Is there a way to fix it?

According to the bug report, the workaround (for Java 1.7.0) is to launch the application without using the `-jar` option.

---

FWIW, there is also a bug in `javac`s handling of ZIP64 format JAR files:

- http://openjdk.5641.n7.nabble.com/javac-doesn-t-work-with-jar-files-with-64k-entries-tp103719p103816.html
- http://openjdk.5641.n7.nabble.com/8003512-javac-doesn-t-work-with-jar-files-with-64k-entries-tp109359.html

Comment: If you create an executable assembly jar and unfortunately the number files grow more than 64K (happened with me), then you can not run it with `java <big-executable-assembly-jar>`.

Comment: @SoumyaKanti - You can if you upgrade to Java 8, for example.