# Cannot execute binary file - Mac java

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, runnable

I recently have started coding in eclipse for mac and have made few projects. I exported 2 to runnable jars and they worked fine, but this third one wouldn't run when I exported it. I ran it in terminal and got this error:

cannot execute binary file

Normally I just double click and it works for me, but this time it just showed a blank window. So I tried terminal to see what was wrong.

Does anyone know whats wrong?

here is a screen shot:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/h1xu50czem60ud2/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-26%20at%207.42.33%20PM.png?dl=0

I was able to find a few things out:

the program crashes before its able to draw when it is exported

it crashed on the first loop of these for statements

```
for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
        g.drawImage(tiles.images[Grids[x][y].Bottomid], x * 32, y * 32,32, 32, null);
        g.drawImage(tiles.images[Grids[x][y].Topid], x * 32, y * 32,32, 32, null);
            }
        }`
```

tiles.images[Grids[x][y].Bottomid] is a BufferedImage.

Comment: Please provide more information. How do you execute the jars?

Comment: I tried to add more info, but its hard because i don't have the rep to post a picture

Comment: Just provide the commands you used to run your jars, pictures are not necessary.

Comment: I added a screen shot, maybe that will help, and all i did to run it was drag and drop. But i don't want to fix it so that i have to use terminal all the time, i want it to be able to send to people so it needs to be runnable without it.

Comment: Try running it in the console using `java -jar yourprogram.jar` and show us the output.

Comment: Error: Invalid or corrupt jar file

But eclipse runs the unexported file fine, what might cause it to be this way. And I have done multiple exports.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [Corrupt jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559072/corrupt-jar-file) question, looks like you have not exported as a *runnable jar* or the jar does not have a class with a main() method an a manifest file.

Comment: I can guarantee that the manifest is not the problem, java auto-creates one, and I did two different manual ways to do it. They all did nothing different, plus if it was a manifest why would the other files not be affected?

I still need help, i am so frustrated with this!

Comment: Then you should provide more information and include the full code of your program.

Comment: I cant include the full code, considering its very long, but i did figure out something, the game is running. It doesn't crash or stop at any point, it just never shows any graphics of any sort. I did this by having it update the window text, and it was updating rapidly, and never stopped. So is there any way its not drawling or i missed something. It draws in eclipse.

Comment: Never mind, i that last comment was wrong, it crashes during the drawing area.